# Validation display name using jQuery remote method

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've tried to added remote method to check display name if is has already exists.

Email validation can check and display messages if email has already exists but Display name validation it does not work. What's wrong with my code?

**My code**

**register.php**

```
<?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        try {
            $user_obj = new Cl_User();
            $data = $user_obj->registration( $_POST );
            if($data)$success = USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Smart Registration Form</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-form">
            <?php require_once 'templates/message.php';?>

            <h1 class="text-center">Smart Tutorials</h1>
            <div class="form-header">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-register" role="form" id="register-form">
                <div>
                    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dispaly Name"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" > 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"> 
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" type="submit" id="submit_btn" data-loading-text="Signing Up....">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            <div class="form-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <a href="forget_password.php"> Forgot password? </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        <a href="index.php"> Sign In </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->


    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**register.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#register-form").validate({
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('#submit_btn').button('loading');
            form.submit();
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true,
                name: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "check-name.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                      name: function() {
                        return $( "#name" ).val();
                      }
                    }
                  }
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "check-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $( "#email" ).val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            password : {
                required : true
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Please enter name",
                remote : "Diaplay name already exists"
            },
            email : {
                required : "Please enter email",
                remote : "Email already exists"
            },
            password : {
                required : "Please enter password"
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : "Please enter confirm password",
                equalTo: "Password and confirm password doesn't match"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });


});
```

**check-name.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$db = new Cl_DBclass();
if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $query = " SELECT count(name) cnt FROM users where name = '$name' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($data['cnt'] > 0){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

**check-email.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$db = new Cl_DBclass();

if( isset( $_POST['password'] ) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password =md5( trim( $_POST['password'] ) );
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if( !empty( $email) && !empty($password) ){
        $query = " SELECT count(email) cnt FROM users where password = '$password' and email = '$email' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($data['cnt'] == 1){
            echo 'true';
        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
    exit;
}

if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = " SELECT count(email) cnt FROM users where email = '$email' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($data['cnt'] > 0){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you give check-email.php code?

Comment: @SarangaR check-email.php added. :)

Comment: "does not work" is a vague statement. what exactly does not work? what errors are you getting? what does the browser's console output?

Comment: @low_rents it doesn't check display name if is already exists.